# New catalog option disabled in ACC

Tags: atg

When I open ATG Control Center(ACC),the New Catalog option is disabled under Catalog Management -> Catalogs.How can I enable this?How can I create a new catalog?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to create it through the ACC? If you are using the BCC then the catalog will not show up if you created it outside it. You can create new catalogs in the BCC, and depending on your version of ATG, also link it to the site that it relates to.